# How we prove that the collection of all step functions on R is a vector space??

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Since I know the basics of step functions and vector space. To prove the above we firstly need a basic representation of function for further steps but I am unable to define since by step functions we mean a finite linear combination of characteristic functions of semiopen interval [a,b) which is subset of R.
Here whether we define the linear combination and the define vector addition and scalar multiplication on it..
What will be the representation??

Comment: Abstractly, adding step functions works just like adding functions in general. Calculation-wise, adding step functions works just like adding functions in general. Are you having issues because adding step functions specifically by using their characteristic-function-representation seems difficult?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $a\in\Bbb R$, let
$$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}1&x<a\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and 
$$f_\infty(x)=1. $$
Show that step functions are precisely the linear combinations of such functions.